# Can't add project from local Maven repository as a dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, dependencies, m2eclipse

I've written a new Maven project and for now let's call it *Utils*. I've installed it successfully in my local Maven repository. At least the targets `clean install` print `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` in the end. I can also find the jar when I navigate to it manually through the Windows Explorer.

Now there's another project called *Import* I've written that should have *Utils* as a dependency. When I now add it to the pom with the scope *compile* and run the goals `eclipse:eclipse` I'm again getting the message `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`. But unfortunately, the *Utils* project isn't in the referenced libraries of *Import*.

When I want to add it in the POM view of the Maven Eclipse plugin, *Utils* is also not found. Interestingly, when I specify an erroneous version of *Utils*, I'm getting a warning when I want to install *Import* with Maven.

Do you know where I'm wrong?

Comment: Could be a configuration issue of you maven eclipse plugin. Are you using m2eclipse or something different?

Comment: I'm using m2eclipse. But I'm calling the Maven goals with the maven.bat configured as an external tool.

Comment: Strange thing: When I run `assembly:assembly` on *Import* with the dependencies added, *Utils* is included in the created .zip file.

Comment: What do you mean by
> the Utils project isn't in the referenced libraries of Import.

Maven dependencies show up in Eclipse under the `Maven Dependencies` container. If you experience problems with dependencies not being applied to the Eclipse project use the context menu action `Maven` -> `Update Dependencies` or `Update Project Configuration` of your project within Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you're using m2eclipse, then it's using *workspace resolution* by default to resolve dependencies (*Import* depends on the *Utils* project **of your workspace** and *Utils* won't be listed in the referenced libraries). In other words, the dependency is there but not where you're looking for it.
- You can run `mvn dependency:tree` on *Import* **on the command line** to confirm everything is ok. You should see *Utils* in the printed tree.
- If you're using m2eclipse, don't use the maven eclipse plugin (`eclipse:eclipse`), import your project as an **Existing Maven Projects**.
- Not directly related by I wonder why you are calling maven as an external tool.

Comment: Because of your first tip I found out that I haven't had "Maven Dependency Management" enabled. Therefore Eclipse didn't recognize that I had access to members of the *Utils* project from *Import*.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the maven eclipse plugin ignore projects in your workspace, you can also set the property `useProjectReferences` to `false`.
For example by adding this section to your `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.8</version>
  <configuration>
    <useProjectReferences>false</useProjectReferences>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```